# try to understand The Iterator interface in php

Tags: php

I am reading http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php, but had a hard time to understand the Example #1 Basic usage.
Questions:

1. `var_dump(__METHOD__);`

   I know you can use variable here, eg: `var_dump($count)`, but **METHOD** is not variable, or it is global  variable/constant?
2. ```
   foreach($it as $key => $value) {
       var_dump($key, $value);
       echo "\n";
   }
   ```

   if I change it to:

   ```
   foreach($it as $key => $value) {
   }
   ```

   if I run the script, it can still show the outcome, why?
3. `var_dump($key, $value);`

   the outcome is

   > int 0 string 'firstelement' (length=12)
   >
   > int 1 string 'secondelement' (length=13)
   >   ...

   why it is this result? `foreach($it as $key => $value)`, $it is object, it is not $array, so how could this happen?

Comment: Please, try to format your question a bit! http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: The `__METHOD__` constant is a PHP internal value that shows the current method's name (ie. the name of the method being processed at the moment). These `var_dumps()` are to show you the sequence of calling while doing the `foreach`. Remove them of course in your program.

Comment: Changing the `foreach` so it does not use keys is ok, the example is the "biggest" one to show you all aspects. This showing is made by printing the `__METHOD__` pseudo-constant.

Comment: You know what `Iterator` is supposed to do right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Iterator` interface allows the class to behave like it was an array in the `foreach` statement.

Because it's not an array, the class must know, how to behave in this situation. This is done by calling (by the `foreach`, let's say for simplicity) some methods that are implemented from the `Iterator` interface. As it's the interface requirements, all of the methods should be implemented, even if you're not going to use some of them, like retrieving the key.

In the methods you can type whatever you like, even something that does not makes sense in the `foreach` loop (say you do not increase the counter `$position`).

In the manual the `var_dump()`s are used to show you which methods are called. The `__METHOD__` pseudo-constant is a string that returns the current method's name. You should remove these lines, as they are given for the example purposes only.

Each of the methods from the `Iterator` interface are public, so you can call them from any place in the code, but there is no need to call them in your program. In the `foreach` loop they are called automatically so that's why your empty loop works.

Comment: Voitcus, thanks for your explanation. I got better understanding.